# Имплементация интерфейсов с одинаковыми методами в Golang?

Tags: golang

Судьба велела перейти с C# на Golang 1.5.

Даются два пакета:

```
package pk01

type Mech01 struct {
    storage Storage
}

type Storage interface {
    GetStringValue(id int) string
}

func NewMech01(storage Storage) *Mech01 {
    return &Mech01 { storage: storage }
}

func (m *Mech01) Process(id int) string {
    var s string = m.storage.GetStringValue(id)
    return s
}
```

и

```
package pk02

type Storage interface {
    GetStringValue(id int) string
}

type Mech02 struct {
    storage Storage
}

func NewMech02(storage Storage) *Mech02 {
    return &Mech02 { storage: storage }
}

func (m *Mech02) Process(id int) string {
    var s string = m.storage.GetStringValue(id)
    return s
}
```

Реализация пакета main подразумевается такая:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

import (
    "MyLabs/lab008/storage"
    "MyLabs/lab008/pk01"
    "MyLabs/lab008/pk02"
)

func main() {
    var storage = storage.NewStorage()

    var mech01 = pk01.NewMech01(storage)
    var s1 = mech01.Process(12)
    fmt.Println(s1)

    var mech02 = pk02.NewMech02(storage)
    var s2 = mech02.Process(35)
    fmt.Println(s2)
}
```

Так вот, требуется реализовать пакет storage:

```
package storage

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Storage struct {}

func NewStorage() *Storage {
    return &Storage{}
}

func (s *Storage) GetStringValue(id int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("From the storage for pk1. id: %v.", id)
}

//func (s *Storage) GetStringValue(id int) string {
//  return fmt.Sprintf("From the storage for pk2. id: %v.", id)
//}
```

В общем вопрос простой. Как привязать функции `storage.Storage` к одинаковым функциям двух разных интерфейсов?

Comment: Впервые вижу этот язык, но разве нельзя просто разным интерфейсам завести родительский интерфейс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У самого родилась такая мысль.

В модуле `main` нам нужно объект типа storage.Storage привести к нужному интерфейсу. Если помочь go с эти:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

import (
    "MyLabs/lab008/storage"
    "MyLabs/lab008/pk01"
    "MyLabs/lab008/pk02"
)

func main() {
    var storage = storage.NewStorage()

    var mech01 = pk01.NewMech01(storage.AsPk01Storage())
    var s1 = mech01.Process(12)
    fmt.Println(s1)

    var mech02 = pk02.NewMech02(storage.AsPk02Storage())
    var s2 = mech02.Process(35)
    fmt.Println(s2)
}
```

Тогда модуль `storage` реализуем так:

```
package storage

import (
    "fmt"
)

import (
    "MyLabs/lab008/pk01"
    "MyLabs/lab008/pk02"
)

type Storage struct {
    pk01Storage *pk01Storage
    pk02Storage *pk02Storage
}

type pk01Storage struct {
    storage *Storage
}

type pk02Storage struct {
    storage *Storage
}

func NewStorage() *Storage {
    storage := &Storage{}
    storage.pk01Storage = &pk01Storage {storage: storage }
    storage.pk02Storage = &pk02Storage {storage: storage }

    return storage
}

func (storage *Storage) AsPk01Storage() pk01.Storage {
    return storage.pk01Storage
}

func (storage *Storage) AsPk02Storage() pk02.Storage {
    return storage.pk02Storage
}

func (s *pk01Storage) GetStringValue(id int) string {
    // s.storage
    return fmt.Sprintf("From the storage for pk1. id: %v.", id)
}

func (s *pk02Storage) GetStringValue(id int) string {
    // s.storage
    return fmt.Sprintf("From the storage for pk2. id: %v.", id)
}
```

Таким образом, получаем, что компилятор go контролирует реализацию интерфейсов, т.е. выдаст ошибку, если какой-либо метод из интерфейсов не будет реализован.
И, соответственно, можем передать ссылку на реализацию нужного нам интерфейса.

Comment: Ну, если это то, что вам нужно значит то, что вам нужно. Но выглядит, как масло масленое.

Comment: Выглядит чересчур усложнено. Почему не сделать просто два отдельных типа, с разными имплементациями и конвертировать Storage в нужный?

Comment: По идеи Storage содержит общие ресурсы. В двух типах ресурсы будут распределяться. В моём случае для пакета `main` сколько типов было столько и осталось, т.е. не произошло усложнения.

Comment: Не совсем понял про "ресурсы будут распределяться". Я говорю о том, чтобы сделать например `type Storage1 Storage` и `type Storage2 Storage`, то есть по сути alias'ы, единственным смыслом которых является собственный метод `GetStringValue`.

Comment: @Ainar-G в этом случае в `main` придется оперировать 5 типами вместо 3. Для `main` код усложняется, а так вся сложность скрыта в пакете `storage`.

Comment: @MaLS Так что вам мешает [скрыть типы](http://play.golang.org/p/hDlA3JONts)? API получается как вам нравится, но при этом без странных "ссылок на родителя" и лишних полей.

Comment: @Ainar-G Можно как и у вас. Просто в моём случае я хотел хранить некоторые данные относительно интерфейса.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно, чтобы в разных модулях один и тот же метод делал разное, то это можно сделать только двумя типами:

```
type Storage struct {}

func (s Storage) GetStringValue(id int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("From the storage for pk1. id: %v.", id)
}

type FancyStorage Storage

func (s FancyStorage) GetStringValue(id int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("From the storage for pk2. id: %v.", id)
}
```

Пример: http://play.golang.org/p/wvd1URcR_X.

Answer (score 0):

Так как раз не нужно никуда привязывать. Т.е. тут не нужно, как в C# или Java указывать, что Storage реализует интерфейс.

Comment: Я спрашиваю, как прирезать функции. Лучше скажи, как сделать.

Comment: @MaLS, Что значит "прирезать функции"? Вот есть Storage c функцией GetStringValue, объект этого типа можно передать pk02.NewMech02(storage) и pk01.NewMech01(storage). В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Написал свой [вариант ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462609/11230).